# How to insert values retrieved from one app's database to another?

Tags: android, android-sqlite, android-contentprovider

I am able to display the data of one app's database to another app by using ContentProvider.It's working fine. But i need to insert same values into the second app's database. How can i do it?
Below is the code snippet which displays the data.

```
    public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> loader, Cursor cursor) {
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    StringBuilder res=new StringBuilder();
    while (!cursor.isAfterLast()) {
        String id=cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("id"));
        String name=cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("name"));
        boolean result=dbhelper.insertData(id,name);
        res.append("\n"+id+ "-"+ name);
        cursor.moveToNext();
    }

    resultView.setText(res);

}
```

And this is my db class method to insert the data.

```
 public boolean insertData(String id,String name){
    SQLiteDatabase db=this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues values=new ContentValues();
    values.put("id",id);
    values.put("name",name);
    long res=db.insert(TABLE_NAME,null,values);
    if (res==-1){
        return false;
    }else {
        return true;
    }
```

Logcat is:

```
       Process: com.canre.backup1, PID: 2953
                                                  java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.execSQL(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
                                                 at com.canre.backup1.DatabaseHelper.onCreate(DatabaseHelper.java:25)
                                                 at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getDatabaseLocked(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:251)
                                                 at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:163)
                                                 at com.canre.backup1.DatabaseHelper.insertData(DatabaseHelper.java:34)
                                                 at com.canre.backup1.MainActivity.onLoadFinished(MainActivity.java:58)
                                                 at com.canre.backup1.MainActivity.onLoadFinished(MainActivity.java:22)
```

Comment: isn't it obvious? call `insertData` inside while loop ... to optimize it a little bit it would be good to do this in transaction

Comment: Hey @Selvin I've done it but it's throwing me nullpointerexception.

Answer (score -1):

Make a method for insertion of data in your database handler class

```
  public long insert(String id,String name)
{
    SQLiteDatabase db=getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues values=new ContentValues();
    values.put("name",name);
    values.put("id",id);
    return db.insert("test",null,values);
}
```

Then take a button to set the data in the database

```
button_ins.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            long i=hlpr.insert(id,name);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),i+": is Inserted",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
    });
```

test -> class name

hlpr -> object of database helper class

insert -> method for insertion